# Repeat a command with diffrent data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I´m developing an Excel Makro right now. 
Wanted to know, how I can repeat some lines of code using different data, without copy and paste.

Looking forward for your answers : )
This is my current code:

```
Sub deleteredundant()

Windows("Test1.xlsm").Activate
If Range("A6") = Range("A7") And Range("B6") = Range("B7") Then
Range("A7:B7").Select
Selection.ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: To repeat code, you want to embed it in a `Loop` that switches the variables out each time.

Comment: I thought so. But I don´t really know how to implement this variable-switching. (Sorry just learning VBA-programming)

Comment: What are you looking to loop through? There are a few ways to do a loop, and choosing which one is most efficient kind of depends on what you're looping.  You can also do a `For each x in y` loop, or perhaps a `Do While` loop ...

Comment: @BruceWayne My intention was to go throgh a list of names and another list of dates. In this list I allways want to compare two names and two dates at a time. If I have the same name AND the same date, I just want to delete one of the lines. After that, I want to repeat this procedure with the next two lines.

Comment: Have you tried the built-in "Remove Duplicates" (under the "Data" tab)?  I think that may work for you as well.  Say you have Column A (names) and B (dates). Highlight columns A and B, go to "Remove Duplicates", and make sure that *both* "A" and "B" are checked. It'll look for a duplicate name *and* date that's in the same row, and if found,will remove that row.  Note that this will remove *all* duplicates, so if you want to keep one of those, then the "Remove Columns" won't work. Just a thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like @BruceWayne has pointed in you in the right direction for what you need - removing duplicates.

As @Apurv Pawar shows you can use a loop, but he's selecting cells (if any code says select or activate a cell just don't.... you can reference a cell without selecting).

Another way is to have a procedure to remove the cells, and another procedure to tell it which workbook, worksheet and cell to look at.

```
Sub DeleteRedundant(CheckRange As Range)

    If CheckRange = CheckRange.Offset(1) And CheckRange.Offset(, 1) = CheckRange.Offset(1, 1) Then
        CheckRange.Offset(1).Resize(, 2).ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

The code above will accept a range that is passed to it.
It will check if the passed cell is equal to the cell below itself:
`CheckRange = CheckRange.Offset(1)`

It will then check if the cell to the right of the passed cell is equal to the value below that:
`CheckRange.Offset(, 1) = CheckRange.Offset(1, 1)`

If the values match it will look at the cell below the passed cell, resize that to two cells wide and clear the contents of those two cells:
`CheckRange.Offset(1).Resize(, 2).ClearContents`

With this procedure in place we can pass it various range references to operate on:

```
Sub Test()

    DeleteRedundant Workbooks("Excel Worksheet1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6")
    DeleteRedundant Workbooks("Excel Worksheet2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5")

    'Pass every other cell to the procedure in a loop.
    'So will pass A2, A4, A6 - Cells(2,1), Cells(4,1) and Cells(6,1)
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 2 To 20 Step 2
        DeleteRedundant Workbooks("Excel Worksheet1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1)
    Next x

End Sub
```

But, as @BruceWayne says - you probably just need the Delete Duplicates button on the data ribbon.

Comment: Ok thanks @Darren Bartrup-Cook and @BruceWayne! I will definitly try this!

Comment: @BruceWayne Hey guys! Just checked ist. Delete Duplicates werks perfect. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

try the below.

```
Sub deleteredundant()

Windows("Test1.xlsm").Activate

x = 1

Do While Range("a" & x).Formula <> ""

If Range("A" & x) = Range("A" & (x + 1)) And Range("B6" & x) = Range("B7" & (x + 1)) Then
Rows(x & ":" & x).Select
With Selection
.Delete EntireRow
End With

End If
x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub
```